# AngularJS: Server-side validation of multiple forms

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

```
<form name="bigForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div class="form" ng-repeat="cake in cakes">
        <ng-form name="innerForm">
            <input type="text" name="cakeName" ng-model="cake.name">
            <input type="number" name="cakePrice" ng-model="cake.price">
        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On sumbit I send:

```
{
    [
     { name: "CakeA", price: 111},
     { name: "CakeB", price: 222}
    ]
}
```

Server response is:

```
{
    [
        { isCakeOk: true },
        { isCakeOk: false, errors: [{ name: "That's a bad name for a cake" }] }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to set 'serverValidation' $error on the right input in the right form. How do I do it? In a single form I'd use bigForm.cakeName.$setValidity('serverValidation', false), but what if I have many (ng-)forms created by ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the error message based on the server response, then you can do this

Assign the server reponse to

```
$scope.cakes = [
                { isCakeOk: true },
                { isCakeOk: false, errors: [{ name: "That's a bad name for a cake" }] }
               ];
```

after submit action.

similarly you can assign error class to input / label to let user know about the error.

If you want to access ng-repeat form element use like this **bigForm.innerForm.cakeName**

```
<script>
    var formApp = angular.module('formApp',[]);
    formApp.controller("FormController",function($scope){
        $scope.cakes =  [{ name: "CakeA", price: 111},{ name: "CakeB", price: 222}];

    });
</script>

<body ng-controller="FormController">
    <div class="form-container">
        <form name="bigForm" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="form" ng-repeat="cake in cakes">
                <ng-form name="innerForm">
                    <input type="text" name="cakeName" ng-model="cake.name" ng-required="true">
                    <span class="error">{{cake.errors[0].name}}</span>
                    <input type="number" name="cakePrice" ng-model="cake.price">
                </ng-form>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```